# Always On Availability Groups does not have permissions

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

I have configured "Always On" on SQL server 2017, and also created a backup maintenance job using the wizard, but when I executed the backup job I got following error:

*Could not process the operation. Always On Availability Groups does not have permissions to access the Windows Server Failover Clustering (WSFC) cluster.

Disable and re-enable Always On Availability Groups by using the SQL Server Configuration Manager. Then, restart the SQL Server service, and retry current operation.*

I disabled/enabled always on but still get the same error.

Any thought?

Comment: What's the output of the following powershell command run locally on a cluster node exhibiting the behavior? `get-clusteraccess | Where-Object{$_.IdentityReference -like "*SQLServerHADRUser*"}`

Comment: Is you Availability Group built on a Windows Failover Cluster, or is it Clusterless?

Comment: @HandyD If it's clusterless it won't attempt to use the cluster. Not sure where you were going with this one.

Comment: @SeanGallardy there is a known issue in clusterless AGs that throws this exact error when querying the **fn_hadr_backup_is_preferred_replica** function. Could be OPs issue if they're using clusterless AG. [Link] (https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32899291-fn-hadr-backup-is-preferred-replica-fails-for-clus)

Comment: @HandyD Nice catch :) I think you're on to something.

Comment: There is no Windows Failover Cluster, it is Clusterless.